# Prove $\|u\|_{L^r(\mathbb R^d)}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^d)}^a\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^d)}^{1-a}$ if $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1-a}{q}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $a\in (0,1)$. Prove $$\|u\|_{L^r(\mathbb R^d)}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^d)}^a\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^d)}^{1-a},\quad  u\in \mathcal C_c^1(\mathbb R^d)$$ if  $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1-a}{q}$ and $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}=0$ with $C$ independent of $u$.

**Context**

I had to prove this inequality when $$\frac{1}{r}=a\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}\right)+\frac{1-a}{q}.$$
I proved it when $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}>0$ and $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}<0$. I want now to prove it when $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}=0$, but I don't know how to proceed. Notice that for $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}>0$ we used Sobolev inequality and for $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}<0$ we use the fact that $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^d)\hookrightarrow L^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ continuously. But when $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}=0$ is there such a trick ?

Comment: It would help if you sketched the proof for $p\neq d$. When $p=d$, $W^{1,d}$ does not embed into $L^\infty$, but it does embed into $L^q$ for arbitrarily large $q$, which might be useful to you.

Comment: Are you aware that you are trying to prove the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo–Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality)? Maybe you find a similar proof strategy as yours if you search for this inequality in some books.

Comment: For $p=d$ we have $\| u\|_{BMO}\leq C\| \nabla u\|_{L^d}$. To see this note that by Poincare's inequality and Holder's inequality we have $$
\int_B |u-u_B|\, dx \leq C|B|^{1/d} \int_B |\nabla u|\, dx \leq C|B|\| \nabla u\|_{L^d}.
$$
Therefore the desired result would follow if in the usual $L^p$ interpolation inequalities we can substitute $BMO$ for $L^\infty$, i.e. if it holds 
$$
\| u\|_{L^p} \leq C\| u\|_{BMO}^\theta \| u\|_{L^q}^{1-\theta},
$$
where $1/p=(1-\theta)/q$. I'm pretty sure this is true but I can't find a reference for it.

Comment: @Jose27: nice idea :-)